# Is this the right way for using ThreadPoolExecutor?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executor

I am trying to get thread pool executor to work, and am just wondering if I have gone wrong somewhere with the following code:

```
public class testPool implements Runnable {

    static Executor pooledExecutor = null;
    private Threat thread = null;

    private testPool(int minThreadPoolSize,
                     int initThreadPoolSize,
                     int maxThreadPoolSize,
                     int threadKeepAliveTime,
                     int queueCapacity) throws Exception {

        pooledExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(initThreadPoolSize,
                                    maxThreadPoolSize,
                                    (long) (1000 * threadKeepAliveTime),
                                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                                    new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(queueCapacity));

        this.thread = new Thread(this);
        this.thread.setName("testThread");

        try {
              this.thread.setDaemon(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
           // DO Something
        }
    }

    public void run() {
         while(true){
            try {
                // code to get a testobject
                pooledExecutor.execute(testObject);
             } catch (Exception e) {
                 //Do something
             } finally {
              //if shutdown parameter is true
              break
            }
          }
      }

 }
```

Basically, I am not sure if this implementation will actually create the threads? or do I need to use a thread factory? Before I was using a pooledexecuter, which had a createThreads() method, but I cannot see anything like this.

Also is there any reason why someone would want to set a minimum thread pool size

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This question sounds more like a Code Review (codereview.stackexchange.com) to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless specified otherwise, `ThreadPoolExecutor` uses a default `ThreadFactory` that creates all threads in the same thread group.

If fewer than `corePoolSize` threads are running, a new thread is created to handle every incoming request, even if other worker threads are idle. Keep-alive does not apply to core threads. Once the core threads were created, the executor will only create additional threads (up to `maxPoolSize`) **only when the queue is full.**

If a new task is submitted when there are maxPoolSize threads **and** the queue is full, that task will be *rejected*. The behavior of the "rejection" is defined by the `RejectedExecutionHandler`. By default, the rejection handler is `AbortPolicy` (throw a runtime RejectedExecutionException upon rejection). You should analyze whether it is correct to use such policy, or perhaps set another one such as `CallerRunsPolicy` (i.e. run the task in the thread that has invoked `submit`, instead of enqueueing).

Comment: Thanks, that was a really clear explanation. I am wanting to use a handler which waits when blocked. ANy idea which handler would be best to use?

Comment: There is no policy that blocks when the pool is busy. `CallerRunsPolicy` will force any task submitted when the queue is full, to be executed in the current thread. Giving some time to the workers for completing their job (but all the workers may go idle while that task is executing...)

Comment: Another approach might be using a [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/SynchronousQueue.html](`SynchronousQueue`) and implementing your own `RejectedExecutionHandler` that `put` the rejected tasks back into the queue. (Using a `SynchronousQueue` will "reject" tasks when every thread is busy, then by calling `put` on the queue you will block until a worker is ready to accept that task). (This is only a fast suggestion, there are surely some cases to be careful about, such as another thread is submitting while shutdown is being called).

Comment: Perhaps you could benefit from posting another question. Maybe someone has already dealed with that requirement, or knows some library that provides that behavior.

Comment: Thanks, I don't think there is any reason why I cant get the caller to execute the task, so I wont try to over complicate it. Thanks again for the help! Really clear explanations - you should consider being a CS professor.